# How to remove programmatically all the content of a section?

Tags: vb.net, vba, ms-word

Is there any way to remove all the content - tables, images, text and so on - of a section in a word document through Visual Basic ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

With that you can create a new word application.

```
Dim oWordObj as Word.Application = CreateObject("Word.Application")
```

From there you can grab the necessary word document

```
Dim oDoc as Word.Document = //Grab your document here
```

From there, there are many easily searched ways to modify the document.  Start looking into this and you should find what you need.